# Centering text on a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I need to center these links while leaving Santos Fire Department where it is
BTW the only reason that Santos Fire Department has two different tags is to avoid the hover animation.

```css
ul.nav{
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 3.3em;
}
ul.nav li {
    float:left;
}
ul.nav li a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.nav li .navlogo{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 3.3em;
}
ul.nav li a.navlogo{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 150%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li id="logo"><a class="navlogo">Santos Fire Department</a></li>
            <li id="nav"><a href="ts3server://ts.santosrp.com/">TeamSpeak (Temp Server)</a></li>
            <li id="nav"><a href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">US Server</a></li>
            <li id="nav"><a href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">EU Server</a></li>
            <li id="nav"><a href="https://santosrp.com/">SantosRP</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: have you tried using `margin: 0 auto;` on the `#nav` tags

Comment: Do you want them centered relative to the entire navbar width or relative to the remaining space to the right of the logo? Either way the best tool for this is likely going to be Flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Santos Fire Department in original position, navbar centered :)

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
}
.nav {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.navlogo a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: 8px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <span class="navlogo"><a>Santos Fire Department</a></span>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li id="nav1"><a href="ts3server://ts.santosrp.com/">TeamSpeak (Temp Server)</a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav2"><a href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">US Server</a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav3"><a href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">EU Server</a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav4"><a href="https://santosrp.com/">SantosRP</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Update**

position:absolute; on .navlogo a class, might not be the best way but gives you the results desired.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should eliminate multiple ids like `id="nav"` this is important for styling.

Now the parent needs to be `text-align: center;` and for your `#logo` you can `float: left;` like now. Otherwise, never avoid flexbox, but remember the browser support http://pleeease.io/play/

Comment: What I make the <li> tags text-align:center; nothing happens and the Santos Fire Department says the same when I add float left to its tags.